# Rails, Devise and request from desktop application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a desktop application that need make a request to "/admin", but I use Devise with CSRF Token and I don't know how proceed. I can't access the "/admin" via post because I don't have the CSRF Token.

There's a solution?

Thanks

Comment: There is ways to disable CSRF action by action in your controller, but you should not do it as it make the website more vulnerable. Your use case should be handled with an API. You could add doorkeeper to the rails app and allow your desktop app to retrieve data through a secure oauth exchange.

Comment: @Syl Thank you! I will read about it. You saved my life hahaha